# Download traffic data for all websites in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, traffic

My Google Analytics account has access to multiple domains. I could click each domain, go to Acquisition > All Traffic > Channels, and finally click the export button to download the data for each domain for the last 30 days.

However, is there a way to download this data for all my accessible domains at once?

Comment: In google analytics interface it's impossible. But you can use API or some tool e.g. http://www.analyticscanvas.com

Comment: Thanks. I have figured out that if you use the API, and have all the view ids, you can just loop through it and download the data you want.